# Two group of name server records, where to put them?

Tags: domain-name-system, ns-record

I've registered my domain by a registrar that has very poor DNS management tools. I need to point from my registrar to another third-party DNS manager, and then from there point to the name servers of my host, along with some other DNS records (such as SPF records). What I've done now is this:

I've given the address of the name servers of my third-party DNS manager to the DNS manager of my registrar, and then I've given the address of the name servers of my host to the third-party DNS manager, along with some SPF and MX records.

Is this work correct? Or should I add the NS address of my host to my registrar DNS manager too?

The problem is that my domain doesn't resolve to my host, and I see some strange records in some DNS servers around the world that I have not set!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution that worked for me:
i simply put only two `NS` records in my domain registrar dns fields, pointing them to the online dns manager servers.
then in the online dns manager, i put a single `A` record, pointing to the web hosting server.
now, this works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some troubleshooting tools you can do to help diagnose the problem.  Use [this whois](http://whois.domaintools.com/) to look up the DNS servers that are registered with the root name servers for your TLD (Top level domain).

They should show the DNS servers for your 3rd party DNS manager.

If you have the `dig` utility available (you have a MAC or Linux machine or download BIND from http://www.isc.org/downloads/all), the following command will also show the DNS servers that are registered with the ROOT DNS servers for your domain's TLD).

```
    dig NS cnn.com

    cnn.com.        123673  IN    NS     ns1.timewarner.net
    cnn.com.        123673  IN    NS     ns2.timewarner.net
    cnn.com.        123673  IN    NS     ns3.timewarner.net
```

The above shows the DNS servers for cnn.com.

Given this above information, if you perform a DNS lookup for `www.cnn.com`, the request will be processed by one of these three DNS servers (unless the name `www.cnn.com` is cached by some intermediate server along the way).  The same holds true when looking up some hostname in your domain, such as `hostname.yourdomain.com`, the request will be processed by the DNS servers listed from the `dig NS yourdomain.com`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you register domain example.com.  This means the DNS for the TLD com domain needs to have the NS record for example.com to point to the DNS server for example.com.  If your DNS registrar is enom, for example, then enom will take care of getting the NS record to point to their DNS servers, and you will be able to manage the records of the subdomains.  Most registrars won't let you directly manage the NS record of the domain or let you register with them but have your own name server for the domain.